# GCP Bigquery Upsert Logic Efficiency check

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I am trying to choose right method to have the upsert logic. I have tested with sample data of 3.23 GB (target) with 218mb incremental + Update data (source).

I have performed two things.

```
Delete Query + Insert Query
Merge Query

When I checked Delete + Insert Query -> Bytes billed 3.23gb + 218mb --> slot time consumed 7.32s + 28s

Merge Query --> Bytes Billed 3.43 gb --> slot time consumed --> 9.51s
```

I can see only difference in slot time consumed where delete + insert > merge.

Can someone please confirm, how to decide on this, should I need to look for any other parameter?

Any thumb rule on this??

Comment: Sql serv is not the same thing as big query - please correct your tags

Comment: BigQuery is not designed for update. It will be terribly slow in that task.

Comment: *BigQuery is not designed for update.* that seems very short sided

Comment: Yeah I agree with you.. but if in case, if there is a requirement to do, delete + insert or merge which one would be efficient.. please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Posting as a community wiki. According to [gcc](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/How-to-UPSERT-in-BigQuery/m-p/547777), "The MERGE statement provides a more concise and efficient way to perform UPSERT
With the MERGE statement, you can specify the conditions for matching rows and define the actions to perform when a match is found or not found". In addition, it stated to use the MERGE statement for UPSERT:
`MERGE merge_example.table_data T USING merge_example.table_changes S ON T.id = S.id WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET value = s.value WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id, value) VALUES(id, value)`